# Angularjs – Initializing script after ng-repeat does not work with http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, get

I'm trying to initiate a carousel script onto the rendered elements created by my directive. It works if I feed the directive with static json, but if I use http get to get the data from an api it will not initialized properly. While the script does initialize and creates a set of elements for navigation of the carousel it seems the rendered elements are injected after this happens.

If I delay the init with 100ms it'll initialize properly, but it feels like a hacky solution. What's best practice is a situation like this?

Static data – **works**

```
angular.module('exhibitions', [])
  .directive('exhibitionsCarousel', ['$timeout', function(timer) {
    return {
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 

        var initFlickity = function () {
          var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
            cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true
          });
        };

        timer(initFlickity, 0);

      },
      templateUrl: '/app/themes/pomgallery/exhibitions_carousel.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'exhibitionsCarouselCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
  }])
  .controller('exhibitionsCarouselCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    this.exhibitions = [
      {title: 'Rachel', date: 'Washington', place: 'One'},
      {title: 'Joshua', date: 'Foster', place: 'Two'},
      {title: 'Samuel', date: 'Walker', place: 'Three'}
    ]; 
  });

angular.module('PomGallery', ['exhibitions']);
```

Fetched data – **does not work without delay**

```
angular.module('exhibitions', [])
  .directive('exhibitionsCarousel', ['$timeout', function(timer) {
    return {
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 

        var initFlickity = function () {
          var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
            cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true
          });
        };

        timer(initFlickity, 0); // If I set it to 100 rather than 0 it'll work.

      },
      templateUrl: '/app/themes/pomgallery/exhibitions_carousel.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'exhibitionsCarouselCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
  }])
  .controller('exhibitionsCarouselCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    var vm = this;
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/wp-json/posts',
      params: {
        'filter[posts_per_page]': 3
      },
    }).
    success( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
      vm.exhibitions = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
  });

angular.module('PomGallery', ['exhibitions']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a promise. A promise will wait for data before displaying it but it will still run the other functions within the controller, similar to asynchronous functions in c#. Here's the link to the tutorial
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q